# to saddle with vs struggle

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

Do you think the verbs *to saddle with* and *to stuggle* overlap in terms of usage even though their definitions are slightly different.Can I replace with each other in the following examples?

to saddle with definition:

> Burden (someone) with an onerous responsibility or task
>
> He’s saddled with debts of $12 million

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/saddle

to struggle definition:

> Strive to achieve or attain something in the face of difficulty or
> resistance (1.2)
>
> Have difficulty handling or coping with (1.3)
>
> Many families on income support have to struggle to make ends meet
>
> In light of this, it was a shame to learn that the resort is struggling with financial difficulties.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/struggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verbs have a different meaning with respect to the subject.

> I *saddle* him with ...

The action of *putting a burden* is undertaken by *me* towards *him* here (active voice).  And as a consequence, *he* **is saddled** with something (past participle, passive voice).

> I *struggle* with ...

The action/process of overcoming the difficulty is *mine* here, and the object of the verb is something that presents *me* with the difficulty, and causes *me* to struggle (active voice only).